# Does anybody have an example of a parse promise that actually works? (Cloud API)

Tags: jquery, parse-platform, promise

I am trying to get parse.com's fancy new promises to work ~ using the parse cloud API i mean. Sadly, i'm having some trouble - i cannot find any real discussion on how to make it work (the api seems to be all lies or incompetence)

Here is my code:

```
query.find(
    function(results){
        if (results.length > 0){
            return results[0].get("id");
        } else {
            response.error("Nothing found. Sod this.");
        }
    },
    function(error){
        response.error("ServerDown");
    }
).then(
    function(moduleId){
    //do anything here, i don't know, increment module? Who cares!
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("error");
    }
);
```

For whatever reason, this code will not work

I get the error:

{"code":141,"error":"TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined\n    at getModuleIdIfAny (main.js:71:4)\n    at main.js:50:2"}

Which points to the line that reads `).then(`

My laptop will love you if you can provide answers, otherwise it shall have to evolve wings v. quickly.

Comment: The most obvious conclusion is that `query.find()` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: You're likely including an older version of the JavaScript Parse SDK. You need to include a recent version of the SDK to make use of new features such as Promises.

Comment: @HectorRamos how do i include a different version? Currently i just upload my js code to the parse server, i am not aware  of  specifying  any sdk stuff anywhere?

Comment: If you're using Cloud Code, this is specified in config/global.json

Comment: @HectorRamos genius. Thanks. You should, uh, you should make that an answer. Also, in your answer? Why not put what the latest version is? By some bing-ing i found 1.2.7 but there is no guarantee that that is the latest

Comment: We're constantly releasing new versions of the SDK so specifying one version here will quickly get stale. It's generally good practice to update to whichever is the latest version of the SDK if you run into any problems with non-existent symbols, especially when attempting to make sure of newly released features. Latest SDK is available here https://parse.com/docs/downloads

Comment: fantastic - that is exactly what i wanted, the location of the newest version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out? i was using an old version of the parse libraries.

To get the  latest version, [go here](http://parse.com/docs/downloads)

it is under "javascript" ~ well, besides it, really.

To actually *use* the latest version, go to the path_to_parse/config/global.json

And in the entry

```
"global": {
    "parseVersion": "put_the_value_you_want_here"
}
```

Comment: So what's the correct syntax? None of the answers on this entire thread have made that explicit...

Answer (score 6):

Here's some code that works.

```
exports.lookupXByID = function (object)
// Must fulfill with an error when this lookup fails
// Sucessful returns must return X
{ 
    console.log("lookupXByID.entry");

    var X = Parse.Object.extend("X");
    var query = new Parse.Query(X);

    console.log("lookupXByID.query(" + object.id + ")");
    query.equalTo("objectId", object.id);
    var promise0 = query.first();
    var promise1 = promise0.then(
        function(result) {
            console.log("lookupXByID.promise0.success");
            if (typeof result === "undefined") {
                return utilMod.promiseerror(10004, "No matching X ID");
            } else {
                // We have a match
                return result;
            };
        }
    );
    console.log("lookupXByID.exit");
    return promise1;
};
```

I'm not certain why yours fails. This code works and is useful because the standard call for retrieving an object by ID does NOT return a promise. I name my promises in this way and use the logging statements as you see so that I can track execution in the log. I have grown to really like promises and even created an objective-C version for use with iOS.

Good luck.

-Bob

Comment: thanks for the code! My issue was the version of parse i was using, of course. But +1 for code!